# How to use multiple instances of Deal or Announcement With Countdown Timer Plugin Widget

Tags: widgets

I have a widget called the *deal or announcement with countdown timer* I want to use multiple instances of the widget at the same time; however, the widget does not allow multiple instances. Is there a technique or way to use it at the same time? Btw, why are some widgets can't be used at the same time while some widgets can?

Comment: when you say " at the same time" you mean to use multiple instances of the widget ? that would depend on the widget code itself. if it is old and dated, it might be the case that it will not allow you to do it out-of-the-box. better codded widgets can have multiple instances. If you are comfortable with changing the code of the widget - I can point you as to how to do it , but given the nature of your question - maybe it is not the case (otherwise you would have written your own widget..)

Answer (score 1):

The [Deal or Announcement with Countdown Timer Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/deal-or-announcement-with-countdown-timer/) does not use the [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), introduced with WordPress 2.8. Without use of the Widgets API, the Plugin can't take advantage of the multiple widget instantiation that is part of the API.

While this Plugin may technically still *function* in current versions of WordPress, I think the claim of *compatibility* with WordPress 3.3.1 is false-to-misleading.

I would recommend finding a more recent Plugin.